# Converting Cartesian 5D and Angular 2D to Lat Long Alt

Tags: algorithm, math, coordinates, mathematical-optimization

Does anyone has the formula to convert X,Y,Z,Vx,Vy(cartesian 5D) as well as Azimuth, Elevation(Angular 2D) to Lat Long Alt? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You do not make clear what you mean by "cartesian 5D" (I suppose *vx* and *vy* are velocities in some plane?), but for a 3D system (*x*, *y*, *z*) you are looking for the [conversion to polar coordinates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spherical_coordinates#Cartesian_coordinates) (*r*, *θ*, *φ*).

If by "altitude" you mean the height over some sphere of radius *R*, you can easily get it from the *r* coordinate *h=r-R*.